# PyQt5: How to make pyqtgraph work on Debian OS?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have already installed PyQt5 on my respberry pi 3, and I need pyqtgraph to do live plotting. I have tried to install pyqtgraph using either pip install, or download debian version of pyqtgraph from its official websites, but it just doesn't work. Actually, it is successfully installed, but when I run my program, it just automatically quit without any error message. Also when I comment out the lines related to pyqtgraph, everything goes well. Can someone explain what is wrong with debian/linux version of pyqtgraph?

Comment: pyqtgraph has support for `Qt4` or `PyQt4`, not for `Qt5` or `PyQt5`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have already done the windows version using PyQt5 with pyqtgraph together. I'm pretty sure there is something wrong inside debian version of pyqtgraph

Comment: PyQtGraph 0.10.0 has support for PyQt5, PyQtGraph 0.9.x only supports PyQt4. First make sure you are using version 0.10.0. If it still fails, try what happens if you run the examples that come with the PyQtGraph source. PyQtGraph is pure Python so I would not expect it so fail without an error message or give a segfault.